# Binding render function with parameters. Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Normally one binds `model change` event to `render function` like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
}
```

How do I bind `model change` event to `render function with parameter`:

```
render: function(templ) {
    this.$el.html(templ);
}

initialize: function() {
    // ?
}
```

Comment: who provides the template? because IMO the view should own the template, which leads to it being unnecessary to provide it as a parameter to render

Comment: @jakee view has more than one template.

Comment: and different events render different templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
this.model.bind('change', function() {
    return this.render(templ);
}, this);
```

Comment: I'll comment about it tommorow=)

Comment: @brick lol. you need 5 more letters in your name so that next time i dont have to write this filltext.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [underscore bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) for partial application (that's the term for what you want to do).

```
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this, 'foo', 'bar'));
```

So render recieves 'foo' and 'bar' as aguments